# How to run infinite loop on vertx using while() loop

Tags: java, multithreading, vert.x

I would like to run an infinite loop on verx on diff thread. 
Should be something like this:

```
vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
while(true){
}
   //some logic (e.g waiting on blocking-code)
}
```

thing is that on vertx even for executeBlocking threads you have global timeout which you can increase. but I would like to set for this execution non-timeout warnings as it will run forever

1. am I achieving my purpose right with vertx?
2. In case 1 is true. how to exclude this specific blocking execution from the timeout warnings

Comment: VertX already runs infinite loop for you. Any Verticle you start as a worker verticle will listen for events on EventBus and act accordingly. I would suggest to stick to the architecture there. If you need an example, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar use case, when I need to consume a blocking api, I have used the following code

```
@Override
public void start() {
    vertx.<Void>executeBlocking(f -> {
        while (true) {
            // blocking...
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            vertx.eventBus().publish("channel.1", "msg");
        }
    }, voidAsyncResult -> System.out.println("done"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

If you have a condition that triggers processing, the have the processing happen at that point and not inside an infinite loop.

Example:

```
while ((event = eventQueue.take()) != null) {
  final Vertx target = event.target;
  executor.submit(() -> { 
    doProcessing(target);
  });
}
```

The main reason for this is that even threads in a blocking state do consume resources. If you have 1000 threads waiting on events, then the system is significantly wasting time on thread-scheduling. This is why all modern IO processing happens non-blocking, in a similar fashion as the code above.

Comment: eventQueue.take() - is working in a way that after X seconds it come back with responses( or empty result) and then I need to iterate and wait on it again.. (for the next X seconds) and so on...  in your snippet while will retrieve first iteration's message (if at all) and then exit and i would never be able to consume messages again

Comment: See JavaDoc: `Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.` Take will wait till infinity or interruption.